# Criterion with NO.SEMAINE(DATE;2) Excel-formula filter with week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

### Criterion with NO.SEMAINE(DATE;2) Excel-formula Filtre with week

Hello everyone I want to use `NB.SI.ENS()` and NO.SEMAINE(DATE;2) to do a filter with week

1. I use `INDIRECT(M:M)` to select a column
2. I use the `NB.SI.ENS(INDIRECT(M:M);week_Criterion)` to count how many element have a date which in the first week

Problem: I don't know how to use the `NO.SEMAINE(DATE;2)=1` in the `week_Criterion`

The `NO.SEMAINE(DATE;2)=1` ask for a date, althought in my `INDIRECT(M:M)` are all date but I don't know how to tell him read each element in it.

Here is my Source :

[image: Here is my Source]

And Here is what i want :

[image]

But my Criterion don't work .... Could you please help me ???

Comment: I could swear this was asked (and answered) several hours ago. What happened to that question (and answer)?

Comment: @Jeeped Hello, just nobody answer this question ... and I not find the solution ... sad ...